# Int vs Integer: type mismatch, found: Int, required: String

Tags: scala

I type these to the scala interpreter:

```
val a : Integer = 1;
val b : Integer = a + 1;
```

And I get the message:

```
<console>:5: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Int(1)
 required: String
       val b : Integer = a +1
                            ^
```

Why? How can I solve this?
This time I need Integers due to Java interoperability reasons.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This question is almost a duplicate of: [Scala can't multiply java Doubles?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1545229/scala-cant-multiply-java-doubles) - you can look at [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1545229/scala-cant-multiply-java-doubles/1545418#1545418) as well, as the idea is similar.

As [Eastsun](https://stackoverflow.com/users/172677/eastsun) already hinted, the answer is an *implicit conversion* from an `java.lang.Integer` (basically a boxed `int` primitive) to a `scala.Int`, which is the Scala way of representing JVM primitive integers.

```
implicit def javaToScalaInt(d: java.lang.Integer) = d.intValue
```

And interoperability has been achieved - the code snipped you've given should compile just fine! And code that uses `scala.Int` where `java.lang.Integer` is needed seems to work just fine due to autoboxing. So the following works:

```
def foo(d: java.lang.Integer) = println(d)
val z: scala.Int = 1
foo(z)
```

Also, as [michaelkebe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/189058/michaelkebe) said, do not use the `Integer` type - which is actually shorthand for `scala.Predef.Integer` as it is deprecated and most probably is going to be removed in Scala 2.8.

**EDIT**: Oops... forgot to answer the why. The error you get is probably that the `scala.Predef.Integer` tried to mimic Java's syntactic sugar where `a + "my String"` means string concatenation, `a` is an `int`. Therefore the `+` method in the `scala.Predef.Integer` type only does string concatenation (expecting a `String` type) and no natural integer addition.

-- Flaviu Cipcigan

Answer (score 2):

```
Welcome to Scala version 2.7.3.final (Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM, Java 1.6.0_16).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> implicit def javaIntToScala(n: java.lang.Integer) = n.intValue

javaIntToScala: (java.lang.Integer)Int

scala> val a: java.lang.Integer = 1

a: java.lang.Integer = 1

scala> val b: java.lang.Integer = a + 1

b: java.lang.Integer = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should use `java.lang.Integer` instead of `Integer`.

Currently I don't know why the error occurs.

`a` is an instance of `java.lang.Integer` and this type doesn't have a method named `+`. Furthermore there is no implicit conversion to `Int`.

To solve this you can try this:

```
scala> val a: java.lang.Integer = 1
a: java.lang.Integer = 1

scala> val b: java.lang.Integer = a.intValue + 1
b: java.lang.Integer = 2
```