# How do you implicitly convert to Java autoboxed types in Scala?

Tags: scala

I've seen how we can go from Scala to Java, e.g. from [Scala can't multiply java Doubles?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1545229/scala-cant-multiply-java-doubles):

```
implicit def javaToScalaDouble(d: java.lang.Double): Double = d.doubleValue
```

I tried something naive to go in the other direction:

```
implicit def toJavaDouble(d: Double): java.lang.Double = new java.lang.Double(d)
```

However, I still get a compilation error when a complex type:

```
Error:(123, 99) type mismatch;
 found   : java.util.Map[String,java.util.function.Function[edu.xxx.SimulationTimestep,scala.Double]]
 required: java.util.Map[String,java.util.function.Function[edu.xxx.SimulationTimestep,java.lang.Double]]
            EconomicTimeSeriesCSVWriter.write(timesteps(simulationId, cowId), new File(selected), datasetFunctions, isParallelizable)
```

The problem is with the type of `datasetFunctions`; it is defined as:

```
val datasetFunctions: util.Map[String, Function[SimulationTimestep, Double]] = ...
```

I've also imported JavaConversions._, though I don't think that seems to help with autoboxed types from what I can see so far.

### Edited to add a simplified example:

```
import java.util
import scala.collection.JavaConversions._

type O = java.lang.Object
type JD = java.lang.Double

implicit def javaToScalaDouble(d: JD): Double = d.doubleValue
implicit def scalaToJavaDouble(d: Double): JD = new JD(d)

def myJavaFun(in: util.Map[O, JD]): Unit = {}

val myMap: util.Map[O, Double] = new util.HashMap[O, Double]()

//Doesn't work
// myJavaFun(myMap)

//Doesn't seem to work either
myJavaFun(mapAsJavaMap[O, JD](myMap.map(x => x).toSeq.toMap))

// A more real example (if it should make any difference)
//def myJavaFun2(in: util.Map[String, Function[O, Double]]): Unit = {}
```

Comment: You should show more of your code, but I'm guessing your problem is: Having an implicit `B => C` won't automatically let you use a `Map[A, B]` as a `Map[A, C]`. You need to do something like `.map(identity)` to provide some place for the implicit to apply.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I'll look into this and update with a complete example if possible

Comment: @ChrisMartin - I've updated my question with some usable examples that demonstrate the issue.

Comment: Sorry, I led you astray with some bad code in my comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two problems:

1. Having an implicit `B => C` won't automatically let you use a `Map[A, B]` as a `Map[A, C]`. You need to do something like `.mapValues(x => x)` to provide some place for the implicit to apply.
2. The implicits between `scala.Double` and `java.lang.Double` are already defined in `Predef`. Your redefinitions of them create an ambiguity which prevents them from applying.

Your example, fixed and trimmed down:

```
import scala.collection.JavaConversions._

def myJavaFun(in: java.util.Map[Object, java.lang.Double]): Unit = {}

val myMap = new java.util.HashMap[Object, Double]()

myJavaFun(mapAsJavaMap(myMap.mapValues(x => x)))
```